# How to upload file to Oracle DB as Blob/Clob using Helidon SE REST Services

Tags: java, oracle, rest, file, helidon

I am new to Helidon SE and would like to know if there is a way to upload files to Oracle DB (Blob/Clob Column) via REST service created using Helidon SE.

Answer (score 0):

File upload/download example available at Helidon repository: https://github.com/oracle/helidon/tree/master/examples/media/multipart

However this example uses disk to store/retrieve the file but you can replace that to JDBC read/insert.

Depending on the LOB size probably it's better to upload/download the file in a reactive way (like the example does above) and read/insert the bits when you have all of them.

(In addition [Oracle DB 20c available in preview with JDBC Reactive extension](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjdbc/jdbc-reactive-extensions.html#GUID-1C40C43B-3823-4848-8B5A-D2F97A82F79B) what I haven't checked but most likely with that you can make it fully reactive from end-to-end.)